# Swift - How to programmatically rotate a UIImageView in UITableViewHeader

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, header, tableview

I have built a UITableView with collapsable sections and with the code I have written I can manage to change the title of the button in the header.
Then I decided that I want a rotating arrow in a UIImageView on the right, so I built it.

Here's how I built the interface:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // Create a UIView with title and button inside
    let myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 36))
    myView.backgroundColor = .red

    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openClose), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.tag = section
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    let myImageVIew: UIImageView = {
       let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.image = UIImage(named: "HeaderImage")
        iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return iv
    }()

    myView.addSubview(myImageVIew)
    myImageVIew.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageVIew.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageVIew.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    myImageVIew.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    myView.addSubview(button)
    button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    button.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myView.heightAnchor).isActive = true

    return myView
}
```

And here's how I open/close the sections:

```
@objc
private func openClose(button: UIButton) {
    let section = button.tag
    var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
    for row in storedData[section].names.indices {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        indexPaths.append(indexPath)
    }

    let isExpanded = storedData[section].isExpanded
    storedData[section].isExpanded = !isExpanded

    if isExpanded {
        // Here the code to rotate the image
    } else {
        // Here the code to rotate the image
    }

    if !isExpanded {
        tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    } else {
        tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to access the UIImageView from the openClose() function?
If there isn't, how can I correct this code?

Also here's the struct that allows everything to work:

```
struct ExpandableNames {
var isExpanded: Bool
let names: [String]
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I managed to do it:
I added into my openClose() function this code.

```
    let section = sender.tag
    let subs = sender.superview?.subviews

    let image = subs?[0] as! UIImageView
    image.image = UIImage(named: "HeaderImage")
```

This allows me to rotate the Image with a normal CGAffineTransform.

Answer (score 0):

A clean approach would be to subclass the UIView (you also might want to look into UITableViewHeaderFooterView which is reusable if you have performance problems). Then use layout driven UI animations - see https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/233/

To access the header view from your openClose action, you could query the delegate method tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:). You can probably structure this better a bit later, using the tag property doesn't seem very scalable, but you can refactor a little later.

Comment: What does "query the delegate method" mean?

Comment: sorry if it wasn't clear, i just meant that there's nothing to stop you calling your own implementation of  tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:) from inside openClose() if you have target/object graph set up appropriately

Comment: I managed to do it. I'll modify the question with the right answer